# Tektro Novela MD-M311 mechanical disc brake replacement

Tags: brakes, mechanical, disc-brake

I have bought an electric mountain bike with Tektro Novela MD-M311 mechanical disc brakes and love the bike; however I find the brakes squeal quite badly, and I am looking at replacing the rotors and calipers only with another mechanical disc brake. Can anyone suggest a better mechanical disc brake available?  I can't switch to hydraulic as the handles have electronic switches in them.

Comment: Sounds like the bike shop has not bedded in the brake pads.  No point spending more money on replacing bits until you try the simple best practices first.   Since you bought it new, most bike shops offer a 2-6 week service to tweak up cable stretch and minor fitment issues.  Squeaky brakes should be covered.    If you bought the bike on line, you're going to have to sort it yourself.   And if you're thinking your wallet will fix the problem, the new new brake pads will also need bedding in.

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this incorrectly. Although some brakes are more prone to squealing than others, replacement is expensive and rarely needed. Brake squeal is a function of the brake, frame, rotor and wheel interaction, so there is still no certainty a new brake will fix the problem.

I won't go into details as solution to squealing brakes is well covered elsewhere, however things to try are

- Bed brake properly
- Align Calipers
- Clean contaminated rotors and pads
- Organic rather than metallic pads
- New disc rotors

As mentioned already - if a new bike take it back to the shop and ask them to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

We've got an electric bike with a tektro mechanical front disc brake. They squealed like mad when we got it. I'm no disc brake expert (though I think I know more about them than the department store the bike came from) but a little tweaking helped. There isn't much adjustment on such basic brakes anyway.

Over time they got better again, but they still squeak a little at times.

I think the reason they put them on isn't so much stopping power in good conditions (my v-brakes are better) but reliability. They don't wear too fast and they stop well in the wet.